# PowerShell Windows License Type

Tags: windows, powershell

I am trying to pull the Windows license type, I can do it with the following command but it takes forever, is there a quicker PowerShell command for accomplishing this?

See code below for what I've tried.

```
(Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct |
  Where-Object -FilterScript { 
    ($_.Description -like "W*" -and 
    $_.licensestatus -eq 1 ) 
  } |
    Select-Object -First 1 -ExpandProperty Description
) -replace '.*(VOLUME_MAK|OEM_SLP|RETAIL|OEM_COA_NSLP|OEM_COA_SLP).*', '$1'
```

I get the expected result but it is slow.

Comment: I also found another option that works a little quicker.  `(cscript c:\windows\system32\slmgr.vbs /dlv) -match '(VOLUME_MAK|OEM_SLP|RETAIL|OEM_COA_NSLP|OEM_COA_SLP)[^=Retail]' -replace '.*, ' -replace '\s.+'`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Get-CimInstance` has a `-Filter` parameter that accepts a WQL query filter:

```
$SLP = Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter 'Description LIKE "Windows%" AND LicenseStatus = 1'
$SLP.Description -replace '.*(VOLUME_MAK|OEM_SLP|RETAIL|OEM_COA_NSLP|OEM_COA_SLP).*', '$1'
```

This will likely be faster than having `Get-CimInstance` return *all* the instances and *then* filter on them.

You may want to add `VOLUME_KMSCLIENT` to the regex pattern :-)

Comment: This was definitely quicker using the filter, thanks for both this and the extra pattern.  So I ended up using this:  `(Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter 'Description LIKE "Windows%" AND LicenseStatus = 1' | Select-Object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Description ) -replace '.*(VOLUME_MAK|OEM_SLP|RETAIL|OEM_COA_NSLP|OEM_COA_SLP|VOLUME_KMSCLIENT).*', '$1'`

Answer (score 2):

Querying at the level of Cim instance is faster than that in PowerShell.

In your code, you are getting the whole CimInstance related to `SoftwareLicensingProduct` and then filtering them all (using where-object) in PowerShell, whereas you can use `-Filter` parameter and filter at the level of `CimInstance`, which is faster.

Try this:

```
(Get-CimInstance softwarelicensingproduct -filter 'Description LIKE "W%" AND
LicenseStatus = 1' |
    Select-Object -first 1 -ExpandProperty Description
) -replace '.*(VOLUME_MAK|OEM_SLP|RETAIL|OEM_COA_NSLP|OEM_COA_SLP).*', '$1'
```

You can play around with the filter parameter and get narrower results. Look here for further help on [WQL and WMI](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/desktop/wmisdk/wql-sql-for-wmi)

Answer (score 0):

Using wildcards in `CIM/WMI` filters may still be way to slow if the hit count is to big. On my setup, the line

```
(Get-CimInstance softwarelicensingproduct -Filter 'Description LIKE "W%" AND
LicenseStatus = 1' |
  select -First 1 -ExpandProperty Description
) -Replace '.*(VOLUME_MAK|OEM_SLP|RETAIL|OEM_COA_NSLP|OEM_COA_SLP).*', '$1'
```

runs for 42 seconds.

In this case it's actually faster to do the filtering on the `PowerShell` side provided you limit the licenses found by looking for `PartialProductKey` instead.

This brings the process time down to 1.8 seconds on my system

```
(
Get-CimInstance SoftwareLicensingProduct -Filter "PartialProductKey IS NOT NULL" |
  where {
    $_.Description -like 'Windows*' -AND
    $_.LicenseStatus -eq 1
  }
).Description -Replace '.*(VOLUME_MAK|OEM_SLP|RETAIL|OEM_COA_NSLP|OEM_COA_SLP).*', '$1'
```

Answer (score -1):

Here's a quick and dirty implementation in python using WMI:

Setup with:

```py
pip install windows_tools.product_key
```

Run with:

```py
from windows_tools.product_key import get_windows_product_channel

print(get_windows_product_channel()
```